# Disk Cleanup Batch File With Logs

Tags: batch-file, performance

I was wondering if there is a way to create a batch file that will run a Disk Cleanup (on XP and 7 PC's), and have it create a log file on the local PC that will tell me the details, or that it's run.

Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a batch file. Here are the instructions: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315246
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/255512

No log file but you might be able pipe it into a log file.       cleanmgr /sagerun:11 > c:\log.doc.